# Update iOS Stored Data with More Array Data with NSCoding

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nscoding

I have a list view which collects some data that a user enters into a form.

I am planning to have an option for the user to tap on a list item, and record the date that they clicked on it. I therefore have created a version of NSCoding which looks like the below.

```
class Item: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var uuid: String = NSUUID().uuidString
    var name: String = ""
    var days: [ NSDate ]?

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(uuid, forKey: "uuid")
        coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        coder.encode(days, forKey: "days")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init()

        if let archivedUuid = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "uuid") as? String {
            uuid = archivedUuid
        }

        if let archivedName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String {
            name = archivedName
        }

        if let archivedDays = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "days") as? [ NSDate ] {
            var getDays = archivedDays
        }

    }

    init(name: String, days: [NSDate]) {
        self.days = days
        self.name = name
        super.init()
    }

}
```

I want to retrieve the current list of days, which will be an array, and then add another date to the end of this array. I'm unsure how to retrieve this data and update the array by adding more to it, however.

I know how to replace the data, but not update it or append more to it with NSCoding. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: NSCoding doesn't really factor in here. You have implemented the code so that your object supports NSCoding. You can simply update the array. When you archive the object again, the updated array will be archived.

Comment: So the array will be updated across many days - my understanding is that won't be maintained in memory, so someone will click on something one day, and we will track that date. They might close the app, and then click on something the next day. I will only have the array stored as [ 11/03/2018 ] - if I update the array wont it just be overwritten? How will it automatically conjugate the array?

Comment: You have to archive your data to disk each time you make a change.  How are you storing the data?  If you are using `UserDefaults` you might want to look at Core Data; it is a more appropriate object persistence system for larger amounts of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering how to do this (i.e. update the array to add more dates) - you just have to do this. In my example, I was adding more dates when someone clicked on an item in a list, so I did it like this -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableGet.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        let cellID   = cell.tag

        if let filePath = pathForItems() {
            if (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath) as? [Item]) != nil {
                let clickedItem = items[cellID] as? Item

                let days = clickedItem?.days ?? []
                let date = [ Date() ]
                let combinedDays = date + days
                clickedItem?.days = combinedDays
                print(clickedItem?.days)

                NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(items, toFile: filePath)

            }
        }

    }
```

Essentially unarchived my data with NSKeyedUnarchiver, got the array from that data, and then added more to that specific array. Zipped it all back up, and posted it back into storage.

Not too hard actually.